# TFS source code binding issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, tfvc

I have migrated a MVC4 web application version controlled in VSS 2005 to TFS 2015 and that migration is successful.

Then I tried to open the project in VS 2010 (Since VS2015 does not support)
It gives me following error. How do I connect to TFS successfully

Error message:

> The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding
>   information cannot be found. It is possible that the MSSCCPRJ.SCC file
>   or another item that holds the source control settings for the
>   solution, has been deleted. Because it is not possible to recover this
>   missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are
>   missing will be treated as not under source control.

Using:

- Windows server 2012 + Updates
- SQL 2014
- TFS 2015 (Version 14.0.24712.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open <kbd>file</kbd> - <kbd>Source Control</kbd> - <kbd>Change Source Control...</kbd> Select all projects and click the <kbd>Bind...</kbd> button. That should re-create the binding, if the files are in a valid TFS workspace.

Since you're mixing and matching VS2010 and VS2015, you may first need to set your workspace to "Server" instead of the default for 2015's "Local". VS2010 doesn't support local workspaces. You can change this setting from Visual Studio 2015 only.